# Android no on screen keybord ( only voice )

Tags: android, android-hardware, huawei-mobile-services

> I have a Huawei P9.

- I unlocked the **bootloader** :

  fastboot oem unlock CODE
- and I installed **custom recovery** :

  fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.1.0-0-frd.img
- I restored the phone to **factory settings** from phone **settings**
  and , from **TWRP** , wiped the cache and maybe something else( not
  sure what check boxes were selected ).

[image]

> I am stuck at initial screens where I need to enter **Wifi password**
>   and **Google email** with no keyboard. I only have the voice option
>   when I click on an input box :

[image]

I can't get pass it and install the keyboard with :

```
adb install keybord.apk
```

I also reinstated Android 7 ( the same problem persists )

```
UPDATE.APP in dload folder in SD card
```

I tried reinstalling stock ROM but can't because bootloader is locked at the moment. ( locked it back at one of the intermediate restarts  )

> What happened ?
>
> Would an external keyboard work ? What other solutions are there ?

Comment: Voting to close as this doesn't have anything to do with programming. This may be appropriate on Android Enthusiasts.

Comment: I would say that maybe Android security would be one of the categories I would fit it in. Also the answer may include programing details. I am a developer myself and I am keen to learn anything useful about this situation, at any level.

Comment: This is offtopic because you aren't writing software. This isn't a programming problem, it's a general android problem. Please read the site tour to learn what is and isn't ontopic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot into recovery then mount system and open file manager (in the recovery).

Then search for keyboard files in `/system/app` or `/system/priv-app`. If they are not there then download the APK and put in the `/system/app/<keyboard package name>/apk` directory.

Answer (score 1):

External keyboard solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Enable USB debugging, connect to pc, install necessary drivers and get `adb`.

Then you can enter the prompt via `adb shell` and you can there use `text input "exampleTextGoesHereToType"` and it'll send that output to the device.

Comment: Only works for me with input text 'Hello World'. Thx for the tip